# get cid and lac using gsm cell location after app is background and kill

Tags: android

I want to get the location without enabling GPS. Then I am getting location using mcc, mnc, lac, cid. when the app is foreground then it's working fine. but after goes to background and app is kill then not working to get lac and cid because of gsm cell location return null.

Comment: Did you find some solution of the problem? I am also running in same issue.

Comment: post some code.